# Unexpectedly hitting PHP memory limit with a single PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, memory, pdo

I have a really simple query that looks something like:

```
$result = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM my_table');

foreach($result as $r) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

But when I run this I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /path/to/myfile.php on line 15

"Line 15" being the `$pdo->query` line.

If I put `die()` after the query, I still get the same error.

I thought this was only supposed to fetch one row at at time; why is it using so much memory?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Hrm? How's that relevant? I only work with `$r` which is a single record. Why would that cause it to fetch extra data? ...unless there's a memory leak in there and the extra iterations are what cause the problem...fine, I'll post it. Why the downvote?

Comment: Getting the actual memory limit error would also be helpful (the actual wording used, plesae), so would actually [checking memory use](http://php.net/memory_get_usage) immediately before the query.  You may already be at the limit *before* the query.  Also, how many records are returned by the query?  You're doing a `SELECT *` with no `LIMIT`.  Returning a million rows is gonna use *just a bit* of memory.

Comment: @Charles: There's nothing before the query. Just the PDO connection. It's a very tiny script.

Comment: Dude, it's allocating **32 bytes** and you're hitting a 128M limit?  You *really* need to check memory use before the query.  Also, what PHP version is this?

Comment: @WesleyMurch: See question updates.

Comment: @Charles: Memory usage is 635384 bytes before calling `query`. I'm guessing `query` allocates in chunks, for each record. Doesn't prove much. It's PHP 5.3.17.

Comment: @Mark, okay, now how many rows are returned by the query, composed of how many bytes?

Comment: @Charles: There are ~350K records in the database. PMA says average row size is 159 bytes.

Comment: MySQL, right?  Are you using `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`?  It's [enabled by default](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering).

Comment: @Charles: Bingo! Disabled that, and now it runs. Thank you! (Make it an answer and I'll accept)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Memory usage is 635384 bytes before calling query. I'm guessing query allocates in chunks, for each record.

Ding ding ding!

When connecting to MySQL, PHP likes using [buffered queries](http://php.net/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering).  This is true regardless of what method you're using to connect.  When using buffered queries, the entire resultset is fetched immediately instead of being fetched when you ask.  This is *usually* good for performance, as there are fewer round-trips.

But like everything in PHP, there's a gotcha.  As noted on the buffering page:

> When using libmysql as library PHP's memory limit won't count the memory used for result sets unless the data is fetched into PHP variables. With mysqlnd the memory accounted for will include the full result set.

You're using PHP 5.3, which means that there's a good chance that you're using mysqlnd.

You'll want to turn off buffered queries here.  It's done differently in every PHP interface to MySQL:

- For PDO, you'll need to set the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` attribute to `false`.
- For mysqli, you need to pass the `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` constant to the [`query`](http://php.net/mysqli.query) method.
- For mysql, you need to call `mysql_unbuffered_query` instead of `mysql_query`.

Full details and examples are on the page.

### Big fat unbuffered query gotcha!

You **must** properly close the statement handle and free the result set before issuing another query:

- In PDO, this means calling [`closeCursor`](http://php.net/pdostatement.closecursor) on the statement handle.
- In mysqli, this means calling [`free_result`](http://php.net/mysqli-stmt.free-result) on the statement handle or [`free`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.free) on the result handle, depending on what you're working with.
- In mysql, this means calling [`mysql_free_result`](http://php.net/function.mysql-free-result)

Failure to do this will result in an error.

Comment: I don't think you need to call `closeCursor` if you use `fetchAll` or iterate over the entire result set; only when you have unfetched rows left. Anyway, great answer! Thanks again.

Comment: Honestly I've never tried, as combining unbuffered and fetchAll sounds amazingly silly.

Comment: It does, unless there's a handful of cases where you need the full result set and you don't want to flip the setting on and off.

Comment: I landed here for the same error, however my problem turned out to be an non-existing field name. Causing it to hit the memory limit.

Comment: finally no more memory_limit=x GB