# PHP: bytes exhausted

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I get this error on my website (Ubuntu 18.04):

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes)

I increased the memory limit in php.ini and still no luck, any idea what might fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: That's a PHP error, not a MySQL error. I guess you ran a query that has a large result set, and you're using buffered queries (which is the default). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728106/unexpectedly-hitting-php-memory-limit-with-a-single-pdo-query

Comment: I edited your question title to mention PHP instead of MySQL